# How to return status messages in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I will make myself pretty objective:

An user register himself, after this operation `register` I would like to show some message saying *Congratulations! Welcome!*, something like that or some message if there's some problem like `duplicated key` in my database.

I already know how to show some messages with RichFaces, but I want to keep it simple, RichFaces messes up a little with CSS so I want to avoid it for now.

So here it goes my page and my managed beans:

```
    <h:form id="form_user">
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:" />
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{personc.personb.person.name}">
                <f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{personValidate.name}" render="m_name" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:message id="m_name" for="name" />

            <!--other fields...-->

            <h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{personc.register}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
            </h:commandButton>

        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

Person Controller (following the MVC structure):

```
@ManagedBean(name="personc")
@SessionScoped
public class PersonController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2000186666864113813L;

    // attributes
    @EJB PersonEAO personEAO;
    private PersonBean personb;

    public PersonController() {
        personb = new PersonBean();
    }

    // methods
    public String register(){
        if (personEAO.register(personb.getUser(), personb.getPerson())){
            status = "welcome!";
            return "success";
        }else{
            status = "an error occurs";
            return "failure";
        }
    }
        // others methods..
```

And the PersonEAO entity:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PersonEAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public PersonEAO() {}

    public boolean register(User user, Person person){
        try{
            em.persist(user);

            person.setUser(user);
            em.persist(person);
        }catch(Exception e){
                    // would like to treat better the exceptions here 
                    // should I keep returning boolean here ? or a string would be better ? 
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I have some questions :

If I should keep returning `boolean` from operations with JPA, I would like to give a better message to the user saying what happened, like `duplicate key`, for instance.

Comment: Small remark: `@LocalBean` in unnecessary on the `PersoneEAO` bean.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use boolean flags (or enums) to indicate exceptional results. Use exceptions for this. You only need to add some logic what kind of JPA implementation specific exception the `PersistenceException` is wrapping and then rethrow it as your specific business exception, e.g. a custom `public class DuplicateKeyException extends PersistenceException`.

For example, in your business service implementation

```
public void register(User user, Person person) throws PersistenceException, DuplicateKeyException {
    try {
        em.persist(user);
        person.setUser(user);
        em.persist(person);
    }
    catch (PersistenceException e) {
        if (Exceptions.is(e, ConstraintViolationException.class)) {
            throw new DuplicateKeyException(e);
        }
        else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

with this method in the `Exceptions` utility class:

```
public static <T extends Throwable> boolean is(Throwable exception, Class<T> type) {
    for (;exception != null; exception = exception.getCause()) {
        if (type.isInstance(exception)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Which you then handle in your controller side:

```
public String register() {
    try {
        personEAO.register(personb.getUser(), personb.getPerson());
        Messages.addGlobalInfo("user.register.success");
        return "success";
    }
    catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
        logger.log(e); // If necessary.
        Messages.addGlobalError("user.register.error.duplicate");
        return "failure";
    }
}
```

The `Messages.addGlobalXxx()` could add a global `FacesMessage` to the context, like as follows

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, someBundle.getString(key), null));
```

[OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has a [similar class](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Messages.html) which may aid you in here.

Such a global message will *only* show up in a

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an enum with predefined values and instead of `catch(Exception e)` do several more specific catch's and in each on of them set the retrun parameter of the method with that specific enum value

enum example

```
public enum REGISTERCODE{
    SUCCESS , DUPLICATE, GENERAL_ERROR, SESSION_EXPIRED, MORE, MORE2; 
}
```

change signature into something like

```
public REGISTERCODE register(User user, Person person){...return REGISTERCODE.SUCCESS...
```

also.. you can create key in your language file with the prefix ResgisterCode_ and then return messages to your user based on this, like

```
localizationClass.getMessageFromBundle("ResgisterCode_"+REGISTERCODE_variable.name())
```

where `REGISTERCODE_variable` is the return value from register method

then in the caller method in your `personc` bean return a detailed message based on the enum value...